# Problem with batch script: DOS screen just stops

Tags: command-line

I have created a bat file to run a simple backup program over night.

This are my lines:

```
@echo off
echo.
echo Please select the followings:
echo.
echo *************************************
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Select "Y" if you want to start backup.
echo.
echo ****************************************************
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Select "N" to shut down without backup.
echo.
echo ****************************************************
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Select "R" to restart without backup.
echo.
echo ****************************************************
echo.
echo.
echo.
set /p choice=Select Y or N or R and Enter:
set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if "%choice%"=="n" shutdown -s -t 0
if "%choice%"=="N" shutdown -s -t 0
if "%choice%"=="y" c:\backup.exe
if "%choice%"=="Y" c:\backup.exe
if "%choice%"=="r" shutdown -r -t 0
if "%choice%"=="R" shutdown -r -t 0
```

Currently after I press y and enter, the backup.exe runs but the dos screen just stop there. I would like to improve it.

I would like to add in some text like: "Well done! Backup started, please remember to off the monitor. Good night."

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the line "if "%choice%"=="y" c:\backup.exe" to this:

```
if "%choice%"=="y" echo Well done! Backup started, please remember to off the monitor. Good night. & c:\backup.exe
```

You can put multiple commands on one line separated by the "`&`" sign.

I also recommend that you add the switch -f to your shutdown commands (`shutdown -r -f -t 00`). have you ever had to hit "End task" before your computer shut down? Well, the -f switch does that for you if you are not there to do it.

Answer (score 1):

A variation, and (I think simpler and clearer) solution based on that of @emb1995. I have shortened for brevity. The solution assumes Windows 7 and command extensions enabled:

```
@echo off

echo.
echo Please select one of the following:
echo.
echo Select "Y" if you want to start backup.
echo Select "N" to shut down without backup.
echo Select "R" to restart without backup.
echo.
:select
set /p choice=Select Y or N or R and press Enter:
set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if /I "%choice%" EQU "n" (
    shutdown -s -t 0
) else if /I "%choice%" EQU "y" (
    echo Well done! Backup started, please remember to turn off the monitor. Good night.
    c:\backup.exe
) else if /I "%choice%" EQU "r" (
    shutdown -r -t 0
) else (
    echo.
    echo Please enter one of the listed options...
    echo.
    goto :select
)
```

Comment: +1 I would also `start` the backup program, as the question also mentions the prompt hanging while the backup executes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! Labels, e.g. `:start`, are a great way to use batch files. You can jump to them, `goto start`, or just use them as section comments. Take a look at this revised code. I added some labels, and answered your question. Instead of just running the command `c:\backup.exe`, the batch file jumps to the section labeled `:backup`. Which displays your message, and then executes the program.

```
@echo off
:start
echo.
echo Please select one of the following:
echo.
echo *************************************
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Select "Y" if you want to start backup.
echo.
echo ****************************************************
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Select "N" to shut down without backup.
echo.
echo ****************************************************
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Select "R" to restart without backup.
echo.
echo ****************************************************
echo.
echo.
echo.
set /p choice=Select Y or N or R and press Enter:
set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if "%choice%"=="n" shutdown -s -t 0
if "%choice%"=="N" shutdown -s -t 0
if "%choice%"=="y" goto backup
if "%choice%"=="Y" goto backup
if "%choice%"=="r" shutdown -r -t 0
if "%choice%"=="R" shutdown -r -t 0
:end
:backup
echo Well done! Backup started, please remember to turn off the monitor. Good night.
c:\backup.exe
```

EDIT: You also dont need the case-checking `if`s. Just use the `/I` flag.

```
if /I "%choice%"=="N" shutdown -s -t 0
if /I "%choice%"=="Y" goto backup
if /I "%choice%"=="R" shutdown -r -t 0
```

Comment: If this is your chosen solution please click the green checkmark next to my answer. It helps the community see if a final answer was posted. Or, if you like BillP3rd's solution better (it's a lot cleaner/compressed), click on his checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

I probably would have written it like this:

```
@echo off

:menu
    echo.
    echo   Please choose one of the following:
    echo.
    echo     (S)hutdown
    echo     (R)estart
    echo     (B)ackup
    echo.
    choice /c:srb "  What would you like to do "
    echo.

    if errorlevel 3 goto backup
    if errorlevel 2 goto restart
    if errorlevel 1 goto shutdown
    if errorlevel 0 goto menu

:shutdown
    echo   Good night.
    start  shutdown -s -t 0 -c "Shutting down from menu."
    goto   :eof

:restart
    echo   Rebooting; just a moment...
    start  shutdown -r -t 0 -c "Restarting from menu."
    goto   :eof

:backup
    echo   Running backup... Please remember to off the monitor.
    start  c:\backup.exe
    goto   :eof
```

There’s a few things to note. Instead of `SET`, I used the `CHOICE` command which is meant for this purpose. While it makes things slightly harder because it uses `errorlevel`, it provides better customization and control over the prompt, including default selection time-out and defaults to case-insensitive (which makes things much easier most of the time). Next, I used proper formatting and indentation to make the script more readable and maintainable. I did the same with the output, which makes the text and prompts easier to see in the console window. I also threw in a bit of error-detection where it will loop the menu and notice the `EOF`s; they are necessary because the `shutdown` command initiates shutdown and returns, even with the `start`, so you need to avoid falling through to the next “function” (you can actually *call* labels like functions, but that would unnecessarily complicate a simple menu like this).